Questions on surface tension
I've learned that surface tension occurs due to the difference between the molecules of surface and the bulk molecules and the asymmetry between them. The particles next to the walls of the container and the bulk molecules too have such differences, so do they experience something similar?

Are you asking if there is surface tension between a solid and a liquid?

If you have ever heard of capillary action and viewed a meniscus, you have already seen that the interaction at the walls is distinct from that of a bulk liquid!

Thanks A lot!!!
